# Zend and Wordpress not playing nice

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

Ok I got an odd install that I have to work with, and it is causing me grief. Firstly though, I can't change how it is installed. Believe me I would like to.

I have a Zend 1 install. Which has wordpress installed inside it. so the whole site is Zend except /public/blog which is wordpress. Now the problem is that when I go to /blog the frontpage loads exactly as expected. However the second you try to go to /blog/post-1 Zend grabs the url and tells me that there is no blog controller. Which there isn't, as Zend is supposed to be leaving it alone.

The really frustrating thing is that I had it working on a local install, but the remote install just won't play ball.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you merge Wordpress' .htaccess rules into your ZF .htaccess? Or keep them separate? If the latter, could you edit your question to include your ZF .htaccess file?

Comment: Actually you pointed me in the right direction. The Wordpress .htaccess file was missing. That will teach me to use a system that hides anything that starts with a dot. Thanks.